# how to convert the world coordination to robot coodination in PR2 ros

Tags: simulation, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am try to control pr2 simulator to grasp some object on the table. The robot is fixed as it in the beginning, now I want to know how to convert the object coordination to robot coordination, then we can use Cartesian controller to drive the right arm to reach the object , and grasp the object.
Normally we know the object coordination on the table, so how we set the target for arm Cartesian controller coordination to reach the object.
Also how to keep the orientation of the gripper vertical to the table, thus make the grasp easily.
Besides, is there an documentation for the coordination of pr2 simulator and pr2 arm.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28571/how-to-convert-the-world-coordination-to-robot-coodination-in-pr2-ros/) by [zhenli](https://answers.ros.org/users/1716/zhenli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2012-02-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I guess TF is the library you are looking for. Tutorials [here](http://ros.org/wiki/tf/Tutorials). It is the ROS way to transform between different coordinate frames. For instance, if you have the pose of your object as a PoseStamped (that's a pose that also contains the coordinate frame it is relative to and a time stamp) you can use TF to transform the object's pose to the robot's base. I actually believe that the cartesian arm controller internally also uses TF to transform poses into the correct frame, i.e. passing it any valid PoseStamped should work.

If you need more complex arm motions, I suggest that you have a look at [move_arm](http://ros.org/wiki/move_arm). It provides a pretty powerful interface for arm navigation. You can find tutorials [here](http://ros.org/wiki/move_arm/Tutorials) and [here](http://ros.org/wiki/arm_navigation/Tutorials).

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0